# Why would a black hole have a disk, but not emit x-rays?

Tags: black-hole, accretion-discs, x-ray, chandra

There's [a recent paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1766-2) in *Nature* about LB-1, a B-class star orbiting a massive black hole.

I don't understand how these two parts of the paper can be reconciled. On page 2, the authors argue that the broad $H\alpha$ line indicates there's a disk in the system, and then that the disk is around the black hole (as opposed to the star or the entire binary).

> This supports the $H\alpha$ emission line not coming from a circumbinary disk, but from a disk around the black hole.

However in the last paragraph, they also say that this system doesn't emit X-rays:

> Unlike every other known stellar black hole, LB-1 has not been detected in X-ray observations. We searched for X-ray emission from this system with a 10-ks observation with the Chandra X-ray Observatory, placing an upper limit for the X-ray luminosity of $\geq 2 × 10^{31} {\rm erg s}^{−1}$ (see Methods). This upper limit corresponds to about $10^{−9}$ of its Eddington luminosity, and suggests a mass accretion rate ̇$M \leq 10^{-11} M_{\odot} {\rm yr}^{-1}$ for a conversion efficiency of approximately $10^{−4}$ at such low luminosity.

Naively it seems to me that this non-detection is actually an argument that the $H\alpha$ line isn't coming from a disk around the black hole. If there's a disk around a black hole, it's presumably accreting. If it's accreting, the material presumably gets hot and produces X-rays. If it's producing X-rays, [Chandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandra_X-ray_Observatory) should have detected them.

What am I missing?

Comment: Short answer: because there is very little friction in the particular disk, leading to a low accretion rate. (Not an answer, because it is just shifting the problem.)

Comment: I'll note that there are at least three independent preprints out today arguing that the analysis was incorrect, with signs that the $\text{H}\alpha$ emission is not, in fact, coming from such a putative disk (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04185). Seems like the original group might have neglected to properly model the stellar companion's $\text{H}\alpha$ emission features, which might cast doubt on the disk's existence.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, accretion disks around black holes do emit X rays. If this X rays are not detected may depend on technology limitations.

Comment: Black holes emit nothing! it's the matter, which is accelerated towards the black hole, who is emitting radiation.